# Virtualbox can't access shared folder (auto-mounted)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, files

I am running Ubuntu on VirtualBox. I shared a folder from my Windows 10 and auto-mounted it. 
But I don't see it anywhere on the Ubuntu's Linux kernel. How do I fix this?

Do I need to install things?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you need to add your username to the vboxsf group.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo adduser username vboxsf
```

Then either log out/in of that username, or reboot Ubuntu. You'll find the shared folder (sf_foldername) in the left pane of a `Files` (Nautilus) window.